# How do I call delegatecall and how do I change it to use the following contract to call?

Tags: delegatecall, callcode

a is the contract that contains the delegate call, b is the calling contract,

I wonder if this B contract can be used for another contract also which contains delegate call?

In the end, I'm interested in how in this case contract B should be made in accordance with contract A to call delegatecall, what should I take into account? and if the same contract B calls another contract that contains delegatecall, What should I change in contract B?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look a the diamond structure where you define one main contract that will delegatecall to the right contracts depending on the function signature
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535

Otherwise concerning your questions, the main thing to take into account is storage collision, contract A delegateCall to contract B will modify contract A storage. You can add a check inside contract B depending if you want to delegateCall to another contract, based on the Diamond structure, one way to do so is to define a function signature with contract addresses to delegateCall to the right contract.

Comment: Ok I will read all of this, Also I can't combine two smart contracts on remix when I try to call a delegatecall or fallback function, how can I do this?

Comment: https://solidity-by-example.org/delegatecall/ Try with this example, deploy B first

Comment: Should I deploy to a different address? If some address?

Comment: If you use Remix. From the example, you deploy contract B and copy its address. Then you deploy contract A with contract B address in parameters.

Comment: when i deploy contract B, contract B address load ,, At address load contract from address,, when i deploy contract A?